# whats the term used to describe sending the same message to a system and receiving the same response

Tags: soap, computer-science, messaging

I"m looking for a term here.

in messaging systems you send a request, and it processes and sends a response.

if that same request is sent it should return the same response, (but not necessarily process the details)

This would be like submitting financial details twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the term "**idempotent**" what you have in mind?

Answer (score 2):

I think **idempotent** is the word you're looking for.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence): *"Idempotent operations are operations that can be applied multiple times without changing the result."*

Answer (score 1):

I think [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) might be what you're looking for.

> A memoized function "remembers" the
>   results corresponding to some set of
>   specific inputs. Subsequent calls with
>   remembered inputs return the
>   remembered result rather than
>   recalculating it...

Answer (score 0):

Echo?

Not sure if that's what you're looking for though.